# Load ajax without click button

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a jquery that makes an AJAX call by clicking a button, but I want them without pressing the button, it should work when loading the page.

**This is button**

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <button value="cars" type="submit" id="submitCars">Get Cars</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Script of button by ajax**

```
 <script>
 <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitCars').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      var button = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'search-facet-form',
        data: 'button=' + $(this).val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          $('#wines').html('');

          if (button == 'cars') {
            for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
              if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
                var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
                d=document.createElement('img');
                $(d).attr('src', imagen);
              }
              $('#wines').append(d);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
]]>
 </script>
```

**DIV in HTML:**

```
<div id="wines" class="span-7 colborder">
</div>
```

Javascript will print data in here. Thanks.

Comment: So you don't really need the button but just want to load the ajax as a part of the page load?

Comment: Just put the call in whichever other event you want... in your case when the document is loaded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the call to `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var button = $('#submitCars').val(); //You may not even need this, you could just hard code this value

  $.ajax({
    url: 'search-facet-form',
    data: 'button=' + button ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#wines').html('');

      if (button == 'cars') {
        for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
          if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
            var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
            d=document.createElement('img');
            $(d).attr('src', imagen);
          }
          $('#wines').append(d);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to hit the DOM only once when inserting elements. IF you need the submit button then:

```
function loadCars() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search-facet-form',
        data: 'button=' + $(this).val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#wines').html('');
            var mycars = '';
            for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
                if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
                    var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
                    mycars += '<img src="' + imgen + '"/>';
                }
            }
            $(mycars).appendTo('#wines');// hit the DOM only once with images
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadCars();
    $('#submitCars').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadCars();
        return false;
    });
});
```

If the submit button is NOT needed then simplify that part and remove the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadCars();
});
```

Comment: Note that I changed the success handler to only it the DOM once - outside the for loop.

Comment: This option is also valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove click handler and replace `$(this).val()` with `$('#submitCars').val();`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button = $('#submitCars').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search-facet-form',
        data: 'button=' + $('#submitCars').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#wines').html('');

            if (button == 'cars') {
                for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
                    if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
                        var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
                        d = document.createElement('img');
                        $(d).attr('src', imagen);
                    }
                    $('#wines').append(d);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `$('#submitCars').click( function(event)` part and have the whole thing float inside the `$(document).ready(function()`